Fixture to hold and deliver current to crystal cathode in vacuum chamber
At my internship, I have a small crystal (about 5-8mm long by 2-5mm thick) that needs to be mounted in a vacuum chamber (which is 35mm on the inner diameter) to serve as a cathode with 1.0 to 1.5A of current running through it. I'm the only one with any sort of mechanical engineering focus on this team and I don't have any experience in optics like this, so I made some small sketches for possible ideas. I'm sure there are components or parts that currently exist for something like this but I don't know what to look up to find them. If our application is too specific, which of the following concept designs would most likely work best or would be the most practical to be manufactured as a one-off part?





try using a spring ... take one out of a ballpoint pen .... either, insert the crystal in the end of the spring, or clamp it between the coils sideways

What is the point of it being a cathode? Is it to facilitate a reaction or act as some oscillator? Why do you call it optics? What is to be the anode? What thermal effects must your structure endure? Is your structure carrying the amperage? All of these impose constraints on your design- where can you hold it, material limitations, etc.

Also forgot some basics: AC or DC 1A? Dielectric properties of crystal? Vacuum pressure? (Absolute-more for your materials and gauge-more for designing your seals)

A significant limitation to productive current flow in this system will be overcoming the contact resistances at the points where the clamp holds the crystal. The extent that you can spot weld wires rather than mechanically clamp wires onto the crystal will help reduce this limitation. If this is not possible (e.g. if your crystal is a semiconductor), the design should assure the highest area contact area between the connecting wires and the crystal surface. By example, when possible, sand-down or mill-down or file-down the areas on the crystal surface where you will mechanically clamp to create perfectly flat surfaces.
Before you run this in vacuum, create a model using metal pieces that have the same size as your crystal. Try copper (high electrical conductivity) and stainless steel (lower electrical conductivity). Run tests in air to see that your design supports the desired current flow without overheating at the contact points.
When working in vacuum systems, certain materials are to be avoided. Depending on the vacuum level (low, medium, high, and ultra-high), you may need to restrict your materials to such things as oxygen free copper or 316 stainless steel. Brass and bronze are to be avoided in any case.
Finally, a number of companies specialize in pre-built and even custom designed feed throughs and manipulators for use in vacuum chamber systems. You might do well to do a search and contact representatives at various places for further insights.
Hope this helps point you in a useful direction to address your needs.
